# how to get array key if not known

Tags: php, json, laravel, firebase

I'm connecting my laravel application with firebase and I successfully get the following response:

```
array:1 [▼
    "-KvJja_r0beLtdoRc29f" => array:5 [▼
        "accepted" => "true"
        "date" => "1/10/2017"
        "hour" => "0:43"
        "numberOfPeople" => ""
        "tableInfo" => ""
    ]
]
```

I want to know how to get the value "-KvJja_r0beLtdoRc29f" from this response. I tried looping with foreach, but I get the inner data not the key.

I tried

```
@foreach($reservations as $reservation)
```

then printing the results but I get the

```
"accepted" => "true"
"date" => "1/10/2017"
"hour" => "0:43"
"numberOfPeople" => ""
"tableInfo" => ""
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) have an example on the syntax.

Comment: thanks, i didn't notice it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use can use `$key` inside `foreach()` to get key value. Do like below:-

```
@foreach($reservations as $key=> $reservation)
  echo $key; // output -KvJja_r0beLtdoRc29f
```

Sample Output:- https://eval.in/937628